# How to handle page redirections and asynchronous requests in React/Redux/Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I currently have an authentication setup where the user may or may not have to go through 2 steps to authenticate. A user should select something in the first page and, depending on the selection, they may need to enter information in a second page.

The current logic is encapsulated so that the second page handles the authentication part based on the information previously selected, so that auth requests only happen in that one page (using thunk actions).

The problem I'm facing is that, when the user gets to the second page, if no more information is required, the auth requests get dispatched (on `componentWillMount`) and, when they come back ok, redirect users to the app. Since HTTP requests are slow, the page quickly flickers before they're redirected.

Visually speaking:

```
page 1      |  page 2                         |  page 3
enter info --> (auth) or (enter info + auth) --> logged in
               ---------------------------
               how to prevent ^^^ 
               flickering here?
```

What's the correct/best way to handle a scenario like this? For reference, my current react setup is: react + redux + thunk + react-router.

Comment: Well if you have enough info on page one, then I would just dispatch auth action and on the end of it redirected directly to the page3, so you will not get flickering

Comment: But that would mean having to split the auth logic in two different places, and I'd very much like to avoid that.